# Train your own image with tensorflow?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, tensorflow

I have one image ( i don't have dataset )  I want to train a model in tensorflow, 
 such that I can use that model to recognize the image fast.

I have implemented one such thing, but it doesn't work:

```
import tensorflow as tf
filenames = ['pic.jpg']

# step 2
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)

# step 3: read, decode and resize images
reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
filename, content = reader.read(filename_queue)
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(content, channels=3)
image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
resized_image = tf.image.resize_images(image, [224, 224])

# step 4: Batching
image_batch = tf.train.batch([resized_image], batch_size=8)
```

Also, how vuforia is able to recognize with only one image so fast?. I want a similar implementation in tensorflow

Answer (score 1):

This is not how machine learning and deep learning works. You can't just grab one element and build a model which explains this one element. If you will check a few NN tutorials, you will see that in order to train a reasonable model people use thousands or even millions of data points.